# HTTP to HTTPS redirection issue POST method

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, http-redirect

I'm trying to redirect HTTP request to HTTPS request using apache. It works fine for  **POST** method in WEB and IOS rest services but **Android** calling the the same service dosen't work. Below is my redirection code. Please do suggest me some solution.Thanks in advance.

```
    RewriteEngine On

    //IP redirection
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

    //domain redirection
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=302]
```

Comment: What is URL being called by Android device and what error are you getting?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. URL : http://www.example.com/login . error code 307 not supported.

Comment: But rules that you have shown in question are not returning `307` anywhere.